# Empty space on bottom of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to make an scrollable activity with a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView.

[Supposed to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7RyT.png)

But instead it shows an empty space at the bottom

[Empty Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH5Tl.png)

On Android Studio Blueprint doesn't show anything there.

My XML is this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.bonecadetrapo.imagensprincipal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="929dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview1"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="197dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="164dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/one" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="example 1" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview2"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="197dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
                android:layout_width="164dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/two" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="example 2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview5"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.039"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail5"
                android:layout_width="164dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/exampletwo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail5"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="Example 2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Negocio">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Negocio"
            app:title="Negocio">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="929dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="204dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="17dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using Android Studio Beta 7 and Oreo.
I've tried every solution on google, none worked.

Comment: Both your ScrollView and ConstraintLayout have height wrap content, did you try match_parent?

Comment: @RobertoMartucci it gives the same result

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two images you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it use this code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.bonecadetrapo.imagensprincipal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="929dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview1"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="197dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/one" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:text="example 1" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="17dp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview2"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="197dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/two" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail2"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:text="example 2" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview5"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.039"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail5"
                    android:layout_width="164dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/exampletwo" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail5"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:text="Example 2" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="Negocio">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.06" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="929dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="204dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still shows the empty space in the bottom.

Comment: In your last cardview you have a line like this, 'app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview3"'  but you don't have any view with the name cardview3. So change this to the id of the cardview which is above the last cardview, then it will come below that view, which is now a empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make XML item has id and attribute visible set to "gone", and on code side write method to make gone or visible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can add this in comment or add more information in answer